# SimpleIoc issue within WPF MVVM light application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, mvvm-light

I have a wpf application using `MVVM Light`. I have two class and interface :

```
public interface ICrud{
//
}

public class CrudDAO : ICrud{
//
}

public class CrudEF : ICrud{
//
}
```

I have two viewmodels :

```
  public class CrudDAOVM {
       public  ICrud icrud;
       public CrudDAOVM (ICrud _icrud)
       {
        icrud = _icrud;
       }
                         }

    public class CrudEFVM {
       public  ICrud icrud;
       public CrudEFVM (ICrud _icrud)
        {
        icrud = _icrud;
        }
                          }
```

I'd like to use **SimpleIoc** to inject the depencies. So I added this code in the **ViewModelLocator** :

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ICrud , CrudDAO >(); //I'd like to add the condition here
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ICrud , CrudEF >();//I'd like to add the condition here
```

I'd like to add a condition specify that `inside CrudVMDAO, the implementation of ICrud is CrudDAO, and inside CrudVMEF, the implementation of ICrud is CrudEF`

Is it possible to do this using `SimpleIoc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to register several implementations, you can add a key to differentiate them during registration as shown below.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ICrud>(() => new CrudDAO(), "CrudDAO");
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ICrud>(() => new CrudEF(), "CrudEF");
```

**Inside CrudVMDAO:**

```
SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud>("CrudDAO");
```

**Inside CrudVMEF:**

```
SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud>("CrudEF");
```